# Does webcomponents.js replace modernizr.js?

Tags: polymer

Trying to integrate the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) with [Polymer Web Components](https://www.polymer-project.org/) and not entirely clear if webcomponents.js does what modernizr does when it injects all the polyfills for the missing functionality in older, less-functional browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Modernizr just detects features, and gives you a `true` or `false` result. Polymer would be something you would load as a result of one of the modernizr tests. They work in tandem, not in place of one another